# Selenium ChromeDriver Python - Ventana emergente

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scrapping

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea que tengo es que el script descargue un archivo "magnet" automáticamente con Selenium.
Para ello tengo que modificar ChromeDriver y que no solicite abrir el archivo con qBittorrent.
En principio entiendo que tengo que configurarlo con

" chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("")

pero desconozco que parámetro o parámetros tengo que utilizar para ello.
Espero que me puedan ayudar Gracias

Comment: Quizá esto pueda ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/q/64349033/13419694

Comment: Gracias por comentar, no me ha servido. Las dos soluciones que proponen no sirven para este caso. Las dos intentan saltarse la notificación pero en mi caso lo que busco es modificar los parámetros de lanzamiento de chromedriver para que automáticamente no salga ese mensaje. También serviría que abra el magnetlink de cualquier otra forma

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de otra manera a la planificada inicialmente, añadiendo otra librería:
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

time.sleep(1)

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.left)

keyboard.release(Key.left)

keyboard.press(Key.enter)

keyboard.release(Key.enter)

No es lo que buscaba, pero me salva el problema. Gracias